# "if" statement to find remaining numbers and append into list from csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv, if-statement

I am trying to figure out how to write the logic on how to find and append the remaining numbers from two list.

I have a CSV with data in the format like this

```
jeffrey,192.168.1.1,example1.com,30220,internet serverice provider 1
mike,192.168.1.2,example2.com,30220,internet service provider 1
frank,192.168.1.3,example3.com,30220,internet service provider 1
lucy,192.168.1.4,example4.com,14619,internet service provider 2
louisa,192.168.1.5,example5.com,14619,internet service provider 2
emily,192.168.1.6,example6.com,3357,internet service provider 3 
john,192.168.1.7,example7.com,210,internet service provider 4
```

My list is as follows

```
list_1 = ['3357', '210'] 
list_2 = ['14619'] 
list_3 = [] # List I want that remaining numbers to be in
```

I am assuming using a if statement is the correct way to go about it.

Something like

```
import csv

document = file.csv

with open ('test_file', 'w') as output:
        with document as file:
            output_data = csv.writer(output, delimiter = ',')
            reader = csv.reader(file)
            list_1 = ['3357', '210'] 
            list_2 = ['14619'] 
            list_3 = [] # List I want that remaining numbers to be in for row in reader:
               if row[3] not in list_1 and list_2:
                  list_3.append(row[3])
                  print(list_3)
```

My code above doesnt get the results I would like which would be

```
30220
```

Any Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you should concat `list_1 and list_2`. `if row[3] not in list_1 + list_2:` use like these

Comment: You are right, thats a move in the right direction, the problem now is that if i had a larger sample, the list repeats itself. For example If I had the number ```17359``` along with ```30220```.

The print results looks something like this 

```['30220', '17359', '30220']
['30220', '17359', '30220', '30220']
['30220', '17359', '30220', '30220', '30220']
['30220', '17359', '30220', '30220', '30220', '30220']```

Any idea how to fix it as one list like this 

```['30220', '17359']```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are OK with `pandas Dataframe`, you could do it in the following way

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', header=None)
list_1 = [3357, 210] 
list_2 = [14619] 
list(set(df[3].tolist()) - set(list_1 + list_2))
```

output is 
`[30220]`